# Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps, android-maps-v2

Since long time, i am trying to use Google Map API V2 in simple application. I tried many times, but continuously getting error like

**"Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment : make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public"**

The following code, I think it good from [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api).

**activity_google_map.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"        
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>'
```

**GoogleMap.java**

```
package com.agilissystems.googlemap;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class GoogleMap extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.google_map, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agilissystems.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="2" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.agilissystems.googlemap.GoogleMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="removed"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat show the following error :

```
07-19 20:53:57.928: D/AndroidRuntime(13864): Shutting down VM
07-19 20:53:57.928: W/dalvikvm(13864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c6e2a0)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.agilissystems.googlemap/com.agilissystems.googlemap.GoogleMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.agilissystems.googlemap.GoogleMap.onCreate(GoogleMap.java:16)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    ... 11 more
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4806)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    ... 20 more
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
07-19 20:53:57.936: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    ... 23 more
07-19 20:54:06.295: I/Process(13864): Sending signal. PID: 13864 SIG: 9
```